# Are there any simple to understand explanations of FRP?

Tags: python, qt, clojure, javafx-2, frp

This is a complete re-edit and re-asking of the question.

I'm having serious trouble understanding functional reactive programming.

I'm looking for a non-academic answer in the form of pseudo code and/or just plain english and/or powerpoint, etc., for someone who understands functional programming in general (but not Haskell in particular), and I'm not looking for a particular implementation.

For example, I keep reading about "lifting" and "functors" in Haskell, but I'm not sure if this is critical to FRP, but perhaps an enabling or simplifying thing for Haskell.

I read about events and behaviors as two different types of signals.  I think this is critical, but is it sufficient?

ie, what are the basic, orthogonal concepts I need to understand how FRP makes a truly stateful thing like GUIs appear non-stateful to the FP programmer?

How does an underlying platform's callbacks and observer pattern get morphed into these functions?
Does the implementation language have to support functions as first-class objects, ie would an imperative language like C have to have a half-baked implementation of lisp (etc) to make frp work?

I get that FRP is "like a spreasheet", or "like a directed graph", etc. but I'm wondering what is the magic that makes statefulness appear to disappear.

Comment: You might want to look at Hoplon, starting with this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVXjExRiFy0 and then https://github.com/tailrecursion/hoplon-demos That being said, my feeling is that Clojure allows for potentially more "exciting" "alternatives" to FRP, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system which is worth looking into in my opinion.

Comment: I think that this is a nice question. It will have to be edited a bit, but the gist of it is: How easy/hard is it to do FRP in Qt. I posit that in Qt 5 / C++11 it's quite easy, and I might have some code to prove it :)

Comment: This question *does not* ask for a tool, library or an off-site resource! Here are the questions that are asked: "What does it mean...", "How would I declare this behavior in pseudo code? What are the foundational concepts I need?", etc. The last paragraph "I'm looking for something like a powerpoint explaining FRP in normal english" is a premature pessimization: the asker is simply looking for an answer. That's all. Sigh.

Comment: I might suggest that C++11 and Scala closures read about the same, though.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.the-m6.net/2012/03/fun-with-functional-reactive-programming). Your question wanders a bit but is, I think, literally reasonable.

Comment: Bodil's "What Every Hipster Should Know About Functional Reactive Programming" talk may be useful, at http://www.infoq.com/presentations/game-functional-reactive-programming.

Comment: I think [this](http://begriffs.com/posts/2015-07-22-essence-of-frp.html) presentation from Conal Elliott helps in understanding what the ideas behind FRP are, regardless of implementation specifics.